# PyQt connection of mouse pressed

Tags: python, qt, signals-slots

I use Qt Creator to get GUI in my Python2.7 script. My experience in it is 5 days old and I never used Qt itself.

The main window with all widgets looks great already. There are a lot of *lineEdit* widgets and the texts inside the widgets are constantly refreshed (200 ms). My task now is to implement such a behavior:

1) I move a mouse to an *editLine* and click

2) the refreshing of this widget stops

3) I edit the text (or write a completely new one) and press Enter

4) the new text is passed somewhere to be handled

5) refreshing resumes

AFAIK, steps 2 and 3 may be implemented with signal-slot method. And the 3-rd step is done. But I cannot connect mouse press event. There is no such signal in Qt *editLine* widget.

I searched in answers. [Print while mouse pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490090/print-while-mouse-pressed) is close, but I'm not sure I should use *event* technique with *signal-slot*. And I surely don't know how to implement that "DetectMouseClick()"...

Here are 2 files made specially to illustrate my case.

1-st is a main module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import PyQt4.QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mw import Ui_MW
import time


class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # This is always the same
        self.ui = Ui_MW()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.refresh = PyQt4.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.update_data()

    def update_data(self):
        t = time.time()
        t %= 1000
#        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('{:5.1f}'.format(t))
# as long as the line is commented, all runs ok
        self.refresh.singleShot(200, self.update_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2-nd is a generated Qt file with my additions:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,     _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MW(object):
    def setupUi(self, MW):
        MW.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MW"))
        MW.resize(500, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MW)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 70, 113, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 113, 25))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        MW.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MW)

# I want to set connection here:
# object: lineEdit
# signal: mouse mouse press
# slot: my method which stops refreshing of lineEdit - to allow me new     value
#  entering
        # This connection functions OK
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit,
                                   QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("returnPressed()")),
                               self.my_enter)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MW)

    def retranslateUi(self, MW):
        MW.setWindowTitle(_translate("MW", "MainWindow", None))

    def my_enter(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a focusChanged signal on the QApplication object. For most purposes it is better than watching for clicks because the keyboard focus can end up in the widget more than one way (hitting tab, for example).  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#focusChanged. Since focusChanged gets emitted by the application object for any focus change, you may want to put the slot on your window (Main) object and then call your widget when the parameters to focusChanged match it.

Comment: Too lazy too check this path. The 1-st answer helped. Maybe I'll try - having more experience. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class extending QLineEdit and reimplementing method `mousePressEvent`:

```
class myLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(myLineEdit, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("mousePressed()"))
```

Don't forget to change class name in `setupUi`:

```
    self.lineEdit = myLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

In main file (in `__init__`) create connections:

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("mousePressed()"), self.stop_refreshing)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.resume_refreshing)
```

and at the beginning of `Main.__init__` add:

```
self.timer_stopped = False
```

I also propose to do a little change in `update_data` and create our two new slots:

```
def update_data(self):
    t = time.time()
    t %= 1000
    self.ui.lineEdit.setText('{:5.1f}'.format(t))
    # as long as the line is commented, all runs ok
    if not self.timer_stopped:
        self.refresh.singleShot(200, self.update_data)
    else:
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("")

def stop_refreshing(self):
    self.timer_stopped = True
    print("Refreshing stopped")

def resume_refreshing(self):
    self.timer_stopped = False
    print("Refreshing resumed")
    self.update_data()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @trivelt ! It works great. And I have a new knowledge:  emit(QtCore.SIGNAL()) - good thing.

Still, I need to rename all my lineEdit-s (up to 50) 

I'll try the other answer too. Though it seems a little bit complicated for my level.