# Cannot import name PyMouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent

I'm trying to execute code from answer to this question: [Print while mouse pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490090/print-while-mouse-pressed)

I've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymouse import PyMouseEvent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymouse/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from unix import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent
ImportError: cannot import name 'PyMouse'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an old module that is no longer supported. PyMouse was merged with [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput). Use that instead and it will fix your problem.