# Parameters for calling onClick() function not working?

Tags: python, onclick, pyqt, mouseevent

I want to call the function onClick in order to return x and y positions of the mouse click. However, I am not sure what event to put when calling the function. When I print the event, I get `<MouseClickEvent (420,306) button=1>`.

This is my code for clicking:

```
def onClick(event):
    print(event)
    return(x, y)

w1.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(onClick)
```

I am trying to call my function `print(onClick(------))` and MOUSEPRESSEVENT, MouseClickEvent, and Button=1 do not work when filling in the parameters for onClick(). How do I fix this?

Comment: [did you read this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222016/pyqt-mousepressevent-get-object-that-was-clicked-on)

Comment: @PM2Ring pyqt for the GUI

Comment: You can use pymouse

Comment: Found it.[Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490090/print-while-mouse-pressed)

Comment: @Jaden. What kind of object is `w1`, and what does `scene()` return? Are you using something like pyqtgraph? Please edit your question and add all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using pyqtgraph...you haven't provided much information, but...
something like this I think

```
def onClick(evt):
        scenePos = evt.scenePos()
        print('x = {}, y = {}').format(scenePos.x(), scenePos.y())
```